# Condition variable and shared mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

I wonder why I can't do this in C++14 (or 17)

```
std::shared_timed_mutex mutex;
std::unique_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> lock(mutex);

std::condition_variable var;

while(!some_condition)
    var.wait(lock);
```

Condition variables only seem to work with std::mutex. But why?

Comment: Can you share your usecase for this?

Comment: What's cool about this is that not only can you wait on a `shared_timed_mutex` which is "write locked" as shown above, you can also wait while it is "read locked" by using `shared_lock`.  Maybe you need to wait until a writer thread updates the information so you can publish it.

Comment: Use case is a little complex: I have a datastore with a global(for now) read/write lock. And also locks per object.
If I aquire an object i first lock the global lock, retrieve the object, lock the object, and then release the global lock.

Now there might be the case where an object gets deleted. So I don't want to wait on the object lock (because that lock will be destroyed too) but instead have a condition variable that wakes up waking threads when something changes.

Maybe not the best design but it is free of deadlocks and doesn't use much memory.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is defined by the standard to allow for maximum efficiency of the implementation. If you want to use a different lock with `condition_variable` you need to use [`condition_variable_any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any). Note that the `condition_variable_any` implementation has some overhead though.

Quote from the standard: 30.5 Condition variables

> Class `condition_variable` provides a condition variable that can only
>   wait on an object of type `unique_lock<mutex>`, allowing maximum
>   effciency on some platforms.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know this existed!

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, was just trying to find out how to make that work :)